# Why do I get CORS problems between Docker Containers

Tags: php, docker, cors, preflight

I'm creating a small webApp inside of a docker environment.
Here's the compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  ## Webserver
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    depends_on: 
      - mysql
      - php
    volumes:
    - ./www:/var/www/html
    - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    ports:
    -  "8080:80"
  ## PHP-fpm
  php:
    build: ./php
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www/html
      - ./php:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
  ## MySQL
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=123456
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  ## VUE  Node.js with a vue-cli dev server
  vue:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/usr/src/app/my-app
      - /usr/src/app/my-app/node_modules
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    environment: 
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

Connectivity between containers works fine. No Problem with get requests.
I know that a non-simple request (like a post request) sends a preflight ('OPTIONS') request aheaed, to check if the origin is allowed by the Server.

For further clarification:
request is made from the 'vue' container to the 'web' container

In the index.php file I define the neccessary header.
Here's the index.php file (in the 'web' container)

```
<?php
// error_reporting(E_ALL);
// ini_set('display_errors', '1');



header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8081");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");



require('route.php');

$router = new Router();
echo $router->handle();
```

When I send a POST request to the 'web' container I get the following answer:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Do I understand the basics of CORS incorrectly?
I've been searching a lot and have tried multiple solutions that have been suggested.
What am I missing?

(to mention it again:
GET requests work fine. So there's no problem with connectivity between containers.
The preflight seems to be the crucial point...
)

thanks in advance

Comment: I have this same issue, with nearly the identical yml. Haven't found a solution.

Comment: I believe the CORS standard has changed recently. It hasn't been adopted yet by all browsers (i.e.. FF no, webkit yes), whereby they will automatically block CORS requests if the domains are different and the protocol is not https.

However, I went the whole hog and set up a dockerised https network with a DNS setting to put both front-end and back-end onto the same domain, and I still end up with CORS errors.